# How do we ensure security in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, rest, security, restful-authentication

Suppose we implemented an application web by Angular. The server is connected through the Restful web service.
Since the client communicates directly to the server, data is also provided for unauthorized users.
While all services(data) may not be available to the public.
Certainly, methods such as authentication or HTTPS can be used to improve this important. But I do not think it is enough.

**My question is to find more logical ways. The ways I might use from begin design.**

I would like to thank you for all the ways in which you think.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create a function in service layer this..       
    function getUserAuth() {
         var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('Your authentication String');
         return basicAuth;
     }
    So you shall have to create An authentication like this 
and call it in service like this..
         postUserDetails: function(postData) {
                            var basicAuth = getUserAuth();
                            var url =  'your url';
                            var deferred = $q.defer();

                            $http.post(url, postData, {
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                                    'Authorization': basicAuth
                                }
                                }).then(function(data) {
                                deferred.resolve(data);
                                }, function(error) {
                                deferred.reject(error);
                            })
                                return deferred.promise;
                            }
```

Comment: This code is in the client and visible to others (assuming that the constant username is used to communicate with the services)
Suppose the data of a store that is visible to guest users.